# Как из этого Json от VK достать все City title

Tags: java, json, vkontakte-api

Ребят, пытаюсь распарсить Json от ВК на Java, как добраться до `"title":"Saint Petersburg"`?

```
[
  {
    "hidden": 1,
    "lists": [
      26
    ],
    "last_name": "Alexeeva",
    "id": 112,
    "first_name": "Evgenia"
  },
  {
    "city": {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Saint Petersburg"
    },
    "last_name": "Storchevaya",
    "id": 121,
    "first_name": "Nadezhda"
  },
  {
    "hidden": 1,
    "last_name": "Tumarova",
    "id": 5574,
    "first_name": "Dina"
  }
]
```

Comment: Составить структуру классов, анналогичную данному JSON и использовать парсер(Gson к примеру)

Comment: почему не используете Java JDK от ВК ? все результаты сами сериализуются в java классы